# How to use &/ampersand in HTML/blade.php

Tags: html, laravel-blade, html-entities

Im currently using ampersand in my blade.php and ideally wanted to use this *&* on my code but it doesnt work

```
<li>
                    @include('timesheet.components.DropDown', [
                        'class' => 'call-outs-dropdown',
                        'label' => 'ROC &#38; FH Call outs',
                        'options' => $milestones ?? [],
                        'multi' => true,
                        'selected' => $data && $data['milestone'] ? $data['milestone'] : [],
                        'icon' => asset("images/notes_portal/milestones-$theme.svg"),
                    ])
            </li>
```

in the **label** I have tried the ampersand and the corresponding code for the html to read it as a special character, but however its not doing what I intended to do. Thanks for the help

Comment: It's a string representation, so just `&` should work directly. If not, you can try `&amp;`, though you need to ensure that your `<head>` section has `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: unfortunately, I did try your suggestion, however, the view on th UI is &amp;amp;